# Error importing JSON file into Postgres 16 Database (22P04 extra data after last expected column)

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, postgresql-16

So I have the following file '14.json' which i am trying to import into a staging table on a postgres 16 database

Now I couldnt attach the file..but its contents are here:

**14.json**

```
{ "ChannelReadings": [
        { "ReadingsDto": [
                {
                    "Si": 47.67,
                    "Raw": 0,
                    "Conversion": 0,
                    "TimeStamp": "2023-01-24T12:57:43"
                },
                {
                    "Si": 47.22,
                    "Raw": 0,
                    "Conversion": 0,
                    "TimeStamp": "2023-01-24T13:02:43"
                },
                {
                    "Si": 47.6,
                    "Raw": 0,
                    "Conversion": 0,
                    "TimeStamp": "2023-01-24T13:07:43"
                },
                {
                    "Si": 47.5,
                    "Raw": 0,
                    "Conversion": 0,
                    "TimeStamp": "2023-01-24T13:12:43"
                }
            ],
            "ChannelId": 14
        },
        {
            "ReadingsDto": [
                {
                    "Si": 2.893605,
                    "Raw": 0,
                    "Conversion": 0,
                    "TimeStamp": "2023-01-24T13:07:43"
                }
            ],
            "ChannelId": 12
        },
        {
            "ReadingsDto": [
                {
                    "Si": 3.294233,
                    "Raw": 0,
                    "Conversion": 0,
                    "TimeStamp": "2023-01-24T13:07:43"
                }
            ],
            "ChannelId": 13
        },
        {
            "ReadingsDto": [
                {
                    "Si": 3.294233,
                    "Raw": 0,
                    "Conversion": 0,
                    "TimeStamp": "2023-01-24T13:07:43"
                }
            ],
            "ChannelId": 16
        }
    ],
    "DeviceSerialNumber": "894339",
    "RestartPointerNo": 5514732,
    "NewDownloadTable": false,
    "DataHashDto": "5Mckxoq42EeLHmLnimXv6A=="
}
```

my code to import this is as follows:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp;

CREATE TEMP  table tmp (
      c TEXT
    );


COPY tmp FROM 'C:\ChrisDev\Readings\14.json';
```

However I am getting the following error:

```
[2023-11-16 12:44:32] [22P04] ERROR: extra data after last expected column
[2023-11-16 12:44:32] Where: COPY tmp, line 2: "        { "ReadingsDto": ["
```

Ive tried editing this to no avail
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You're uploading a CSV and the content of this CSV is JSON.  What is the DELIMITER for the different json's in this file? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html

Comment: *`FORMAT`
Selects the data format to be read or written: `text`, `csv` (Comma Separated Values), or `binary`. The default is `text`.* You're importing a plaintext and default format is `text`, so this does look like it should work. Are you sure you're running the exact code you shared, not adding `CSV` or `WITH(FORMAT CSV)` at the end of `COPY`? Have you tried explicitly adding `WITH(FORMAT TEXT)`?

Comment: The file im loading is not as CSV file. It a JSON file.
The file is called 14.json... I couldnt atttach it to this post but its outputed at the begining of this post

Comment: @Zegarek I did try With (Format CSV) but got the same sort of error:

[2023-11-16 15:17:06] [22P04] ERROR: extra data after last expected column
[2023-11-16 15:17:06] Where: COPY tmp, line 2: "  { "ReadingsDto": ["

Comment: Try `WITH(FORMAT TEXT)`, **not** the csv.

Comment: @Zegarek sorry yes I did try with Format Text as follows:

COPY tmp FROM 'C:\ChrisDev\Readings\14.json' WITH(FORMAT TEXT) ;

But still got the same error

Comment: I also tried to import the contents of 14.JSON as a string and that worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have tabs in your file, which is unfortunate for [`copy...format text`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html#id-1.9.3.55.6) (default behaviour) because another default setting `copy` comes with is `delimiter` configured to use tabs:

> `FORMAT`
> Selects the data format to be read or written: `text`, `csv` (Comma Separated Values), or `binary`. The default is `text`.

> `DELIMITER`
> Specifies the character that separates columns within each row (line) of the file. The default is a ***tab character in `text` format***, a comma in `CSV` format. This must be a single one-byte character. This option is not allowed when using `binary` format.

To solve this, try another delimiter:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp;
CREATE TEMP  table tmp (c TEXT );
COPY tmp FROM 'C:\ChrisDev\Readings\14.json' WITH (FORMAT TEXT, DELIMITER '~');
```

Comment: I tried and it worked perfectly! you were right. I probably did have tabs in my file.

I was able to load my file into the temp table and then do a select which returned the JSON in its original format!

Thank you very much for that.